# Program that Reverses Lines isn't printing to Standard Output

Tags: c++

Thank you for your help!
I really appreciate it, this is coming from a new programmer.
I've tried compiling it, and it compiles fine - but nothing prints to stdoutput when I tested it with some numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) to make sure it was working.  The program is supposed to read up to 1000 lines from standard input and reverse them and send them to standard output. Just to reverse the lines, not each letter in each line.  Thanks again.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int N = 999;

int arrayreadin(string line[]){
    int x=0;
    string liner[N];
    while(!cin.fail() && x<=N){
        getline(cin,liner[x]);
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

void output(string line[], int i){
    int x;
    string liner[N];
    while (x>=0){
        cout << liner[x] << endl;
        x--;
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    int i, x;
    string line[N];
    arrayreadin(line, x);
    output(line, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What causes `cin.fail()`, you think?

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? arrayreadin( string line[] ) is defined as a function which takes a single argument, whereas in main you pass it two: arrayreadin(line, x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating local string arrays in both methods, but never returning / using data from these - You already have an array in main - use that. Also note that x is returned from `arrayreadin` - it isn't a parameter:

```
int arrayreadin(string line[]){
    int x=0;
    while(!cin.fail() && x<N){ // Array is 0..N-1
        getline(cin,line[x]);
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

void output(string line[], int x){
    int z= x-1; // Again N-1 to 0
    while (z >= 0){
        cout << line[z] << endl;
        z--;
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    int i, x;
    string line[N];
    x = arrayreadin(line); // #lines returned
    output(line, x); // passed into output
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems.

One - your `arrayreadin` function does not return useful values - you are putting the values from the input into an array `liner` which only exists in the scope of the function - so all you return is the value of `x` (the number of lines read). You never return the strings read in.

Two - you loop until `cin.fail()`. Since you are reading in a string, I *think* you will not get a failure until you have the full 1000 lines read. Until you do, you are still in the loop reading input. Consider whether this is true...

Three - in your `output` function, you don't initialize `x` to anything. So there is no knowing what it starts with, or how many iterations it will perform. Add a line

```
x = i - 1;  // <<< note x = i - 1, not x = i as I wrote initially
```

before the loop that prints.

Four - you are calling `arrayreadin` with a different number of arguments than you define - change the call to

```
x = arrayreadin(line);
```

Five - you overshoot your loop:

```
string liner[N];
while(!cin.fail() && x<=N){
```

You only allocate `N` elements, but will keep going for `N+1` loops… Change the condition to

```
while(!cin.fail() && x<N){
```

Finally, if you want to be able to return when an empty string is entered (rather than have to always enter 1000 strings), you need to test for the empty string (rather than for `cin.fail()`).  You could do this by adding the following line before the `x++;` statement:

```
    if (0 == line[x].length()) break;
```

When you do all these things you end up with the following program - this works, and it will terminate "early" if you put in a blank line (just a carriage return):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int N = 1000;

int arrayreadin(string line[]){
    int x=0;
    while(!cin.fail() && x<N){
        getline(cin,line[x]);
        if (0 == line[x].length()) break;
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

void output(string line[], int i){
    int x;
    x = i-1;
    while (x>=0){
        cout << line[x] << endl;
        x--;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int i, x;
    string line[N];
    x = arrayreadin(line);
    output(line, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Test output:

```
Hello
beautiful
world

world
beautiful
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got from compiling the original example.

```
g++     junk2.cpp   -o junk2
junk2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
junk2.cpp:27:24: error: too many arguments to function ‘int arrayreadin(std::string*)’
     arrayreadin(line, x);
                        ^
junk2.cpp:5:5: note: declared here
 int arrayreadin(string line[]){
     ^
```

So it couldn't have compiled as given.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

N cannot be 999, since the way you use it, you'll end up with only 999 lines in your array.  You either need to make N 1000, or add one to it in a number of locations.  I'll assume that it's been changed to 1000.

```
const int N = 1000;
```

'Line' is being allocated in main, so you shouldn't be allocating it here.  'Liner' is purely local.  When you return from the function, it goes away, so there wouldn't be any data to output.  I don't think 'fail' is what you want to test, I think 'eof' is what you want to test, and with N now being 1000, the conditional has to change.

```
int arrayreadin(string line[]){
    int x=0;
    while(!cin.eof() && x<N){
        getline(cin,line[x]);
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Again, 'line' is allocated in main, so you don't want to allocate it here, and 'liner' is purely local, so it wouldn't have any data in it anyway.  Additionally, you named the integer input argument 'i' instead of 'x', but you used 'x' throughout the rest of the code.  That's another reason the code wouldn't have output anything, or if it did, it would likely be memory garbage causing all sorts of interesting problems.

```
void output(string line[], int x){
    int x;
    while (x>=0){
        cout << line[x] << endl;
        x--;
    }
    return;
}
```

You're not using 'i', so don't declare it.  And as we saw above, your use of 'arrayreadin' absolutely will trigger a compile time error.

```
int main(){
    int x;
    string line[N];
    x = arrayreadin(line);
    output(line, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it compiles without error, and easily reversed a few lines.  I haven't tested it all the way to 1000 lines, but that's up to you to prove it works.

### NOTE

Use of "using namespace" is discouraged.  I know, the text books often do use it, and it does make things simpler in some cases, but it's also dangerous.

Consider this, in some part of the 'something' namespace that you don't know about, 'foo' has been declared.  Yet in your own code, you have a similar thing called 'foo', that is enough alike that it won't trigger a compiler error if you happen to mix them up (it's more common than you think).

If you say "using namespace something;" in your code, and then fail to qualify your own version of 'foo', you'll end up using the 'something' version, and have weird results that can be very difficult to track down.

It's much more reliable to always use the qualified names instead of depending on "using namespace".